# Enable hover only on top/bottom/left/right

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm trying to create a variant in Tailwind file configuration.
What I would like to have is something like `hover:border-l-4 hover:border-green-400`, so a class that enables a border on the left (or only on top / bottom / right).

So I create this inside `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: ['./src/**/*.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  },
  darkMode: false, 
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        ...
      },
    },
    borderLeft: (theme) => ({}),
    ...
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      borderLeft: ['hover', 'focus']
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

It doesn't work. I get `TypeError: variantsValue is not iterable`.

I didn't find anything useful in the documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [docs on tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width#variants).

```
  variants: {
    extend: {
      borderWidth: ['hover'],
    }
  }
```

From here, `hover:border-l-4 hover:border-green-400` will work.